# Django mongodb - settings.DATABASES is improperly configured

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm using Django 1.8 and MongoDB in my project. I can connect to database but when I want to do something in views.py I'm getting this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /make_histograms
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.           
Check settings documentation for more details.

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/make_histograms
Django Version: 1.8
Python Executable: G:\Stamp 2\VENV2\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path: ['G:\\Stamp 2\\znaczki2', 'G:\\Stamp  2\\VENV2\\Scripts\\python27.zip', 'G:\\Stamp 2\\VENV2\\DLLs', 'G:\\Stamp 2\\VENV2\\lib', 'G:\\Stamp 2\\VENV2\\lib\\plat-win', 'G:\\Stamp 2\\VENV2\\lib\\lib-tk', 'G:\\Stamp 2\\VENV2\\Scripts', 'c:\\python27\\Lib', 'c:\\python27\\DLLs', 'c:\\python27\\Lib\\lib-tk', 'G:\\Stamp 2\\VENV2', 'G:\\Stamp 2\\VENV2\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time: Tue, 20 Dec 2016 17:23:38 +0100
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "G:\Stamp 2\VENV2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response 
132.response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "G:\Stamp 2\VENV2\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "G:\Stamp 2\znaczki2\app\views.py" in make_histograms
62.             example.save()
File "G:\Stamp 2\VENV2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
710.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "G:\Stamp 2\VENV2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
735.         with transaction.atomic(using=using, savepoint=False):
File "G:\Stamp 2\VENV2\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in __enter__
150.             if not connection.get_autocommit():
File "G:\Stamp 2\VENV2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in get_autocommit
286.         self.ensure_connection()
File "G:\Stamp 2\VENV2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py" in complain
21.     raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /make_histograms
Exception Value: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

But I see that MongoDB connection is okay:
[Mongod.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZqtT.jpg)

Can someone help me fix this issue?

My DATABASES sectiion in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
}
}

_MONGODB_USER = 'marcin'
_MONGODB_PASSWD = '1234'
_MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
_MONGODB_NAME = 'znaczki'
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = \
  'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' \
  % (_MONGODB_USER, _MONGODB_PASSWD, _MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)

mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST)
```

Comment: How is `DATABASES` section in your `settings.py` file?

Comment: @ettanany

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}

Comment: Did you add mongo config to settings.py?

Comment: @ettanany

_MONGODB_USER = 'marcin'
_MONGODB_PASSWD = '1234'
_MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
_MONGODB_NAME = 'znaczki'
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = \
  'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' \
  % (_MONGODB_USER, _MONGODB_PASSWD, _MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)

mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST)

Comment: Please add these 2 comments content to your question.

Comment: Please take look at my answer and try to make those changes in your settings.py file

Answer (score 1):

Your `settings.py` file should contain the following:

```
import mongoengine

# ...

# DATABASES section should be:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
    },
}

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'

_MONGODB_USER = 'db_user'
_MONGODB_PASSWD = 'db_password'
_MONGODB_HOST = 'db_host'
_MONGODB_NAME = 'db_name'
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = \
    'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' \
    % (_MONGODB_USER, _MONGODB_PASSWD, _MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)

mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST)

# ...

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)
```

Comment: Now I'm getting following error:

'ImportError: No module named django.sessions'

Comment: What if you comment that line? because it is not required